# Rails - Setting the amount of whitespace using Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, erb, slim-lang

I recently made the switch to slim and things are going well so far. There was one thing I noticed after running a scaffold for one of my model's show view:

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie)
'|
= link_to 'Back', movies_path
```

As opposed to erb there's no white space before the pipe which renders these two links like this

`Edit| Back`

As a beginner with slim I was wondering if there was any possibility of adding space before and after characters.

I've also notice that in this same scaffold there was no space separating colons from text. So for instance:

`Title: Rush Hour` is `Title:Rush Hour`

To fix this I've either had to add white space right after the word title or insert a single quote directly below.

```
# Option 1
p
  b Title: # Add space where the hashtag is currenty
  = @movie.title

# Option 2    
p
  strong Title: 
'
  = @movie.title
```

Is there any alternative to the two? I find that for the first adding that invisible space may not be evident for other devs/someone returning to the code and the second adds an entirely new line just for one character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#trailing-and-leading-whitespace--)

> You can force Slim to add a trailing whitespace after a tag by adding a >.

```
b> Title: 
=@movie.title
```

For your second (actually first) issue, after playing around with [this website](http://slim2html.raving.systems/) for a while I came up with this

```
| #{link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie)} | #{link_to 'Back', movies_path}
```

the `|` tell slim to verbatim interpret the following line, and the two ruby link_to statements are separated by a `*space*|*space*`

Also this works

```
=' link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie)
'|
= link_to 'Back', movies_path
```

Comment: Any idea for the second part of the question? I've tried using `<`, `>`, `<>` next to and between the pipe but either got an error or the characters were rendered as symbols.

Comment: The above should work. If not though, give `=< @movie.title` (looks a little strange) a try for prepending a whitespace character.